# Select ALL column FROM Join Table IN PYSPARK

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a data that 'type = pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame' and I want to select all columns from this data df and from df1 another data that have the same type. I creat df from r that is a list of tuple.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(r, schema =column )
df_final = spark.sql('select * \
                from df \
                Inner Join df1 \
                on df.a = df1.b')
```

And I have this error: AnalysisException: Table or view not found: df; line 1 pos 43;
'Project [*]
+- 'UnresolvedRelation [df], [], false

I code in spark, python (pyspark)
I not really understand why..? Any ideas ? Thanks

Comment: To use df in spark sql create a temp view on it like df.createOrReplaceTempView("df") then run df_final line

Answer (score 0):

SparkSQl support writing programs using Dataset and Dataframe API, along with it need to support sql.

In order to support Sql on DataFrames, first it requires a table definition with column names are required, along with if it creates tables the hive metastore will get lot unnecessary tables, because Spark-Sql natively resides on hive. So it will create a temporary view, which temporarily available in hive for time being and used as any other hive table, once the Spark Context stop it will be removed.

In order to create the view, developer need an utility called createOrReplaceTempView